# Firebase authentication via microsoft - Login tab not showing

Tags: java, android, firebase

got some copy-paste code from firebaseauth tutorial to connect a client on my app with Microsoft authentication. problem is, login screen not showing

you can find the full tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth).

note, I did copy everything just to test connection (not including optional code, to simplify things)

the problem stats at firebaseAuth.startActivityForSignInWithProvider method. it always ends up with failure. trace show this message:
"FirebaseAuthException... There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash."

I did everything in the tutorial including registration of my app at Microsoft and Firebase Authentication screen. I ran this code at android studio emulator and an actual device, same result

**my sign in function:**

```
public void signinToMicrosoft(Activity activity) {

    OAuthProvider.Builder provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("microsoft.com");
    Log.e(TAG,"Signing with microsoft");


    Task<AuthResult> pendingResultTask = firebaseAuth.getPendingAuthResult();
    if (pendingResultTask != null) {
        // There's something already here! Finish the sign-in for your user.
        pendingResultTask
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                Log.e(TAG,"Pending Success");
                                // User is signed in.
                                // IdP data available in
                                // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile().
                                // The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                                // authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken().
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG,"Pending Failed: "+e.getMessage());
                                // Handle failure.
                            }
                        });
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG,"No Pending");
        // There's no pending result so you need to start the sign-in flow.
        // See below.
    }

    firebaseAuth
            .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(activity, provider.build())
            .addOnSuccessListener(
                    new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Auth Success");
                            // User is signed in.
                            // IdP data available in
                            // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile().
                            // The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                            // authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken().
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(
                    new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"Auth Failed: "+e.getMessage() + "\nTrace: "+ e.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                            // Handle failure.
                        }
                    });


}
```

a custom chrome tab was supposed to open and allow signing to Microsoft but it pops up for a split second and closes. if anyone had that problem or got a fix for me it would be much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Hey Asaf, can you please verify that the SHA-1 that is registered in the Firebase Console matches the one that signs your app? Usually when you see that error that is what is happening. If that doesn't fix it, please also comment with the version of Google Play services that is on the emulator, and see if updating that helps the issue.

Comment: Hi Malcolm, thanks for the reply. if you mean the app secret than yes, it matches and I tried creating a new one and doing the process again but still doesn't work. I used my phone for that test and the play services version is 16.0.89, the latest version

Comment: The SHA-1 is different from an application secret - it's the key that signs your app when you build it. Please verify that you have it registered as described in step 6 here (the guide has been modified since you first asked your question) : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth

Comment: Hi again and sorry for the late reply, I did as you suggested, addin the SHA-1 key but nothing changed. i'll post some of the lines log comment, maybe that will shed some light...

Comment: /il.co.diamed.com.form E/IdpSignInActivity: Web sign-in failed, finishing
/il.co.diamed.com.form V/FA: Activity paused, time: 151673126
/? D/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: The activity in ApplicationInfo{74707bf il.co.diamed.com.form} is now in focus and seems to be in full-screen mode
/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedil.co.diamed.com.form/il.co.diamed.com.form.menu.LoginActivity/3
/il.co.diamed.com.form E/AuthenticationProvider:There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash
    Trace:com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone still has this problem, I just want to share my solution and my problem which is similar to this.

**TL;DR**

Your SHA-1 Fingerprint may be used by another Firebase project so either delete that fingerprint or sign with a different keystore

**Long Version**

I worked on a project that has a development and production environment using different Firebase projects. We use Firebase Auth to link Microsoft login for our Android app. I got the same error as above while trying to set up the development environment of the project. We used to only have one environment for Firebase so this was never a problem.

It turns out that when you don't provide an SHA-1 fingerprint when you create the project, Firebase automatically adds them when you run an authentication call. This meant that when we created debug APKs for testing, the SHA-1 fingerprint was recorded to the Firebase project that was intended for the live environment so when you try to add the same fingerprint in another project it won't let you. The solution would be to include the SHA-1 fingerprint in the development environment but to do so you would need to delete it the fingerprint from the live environment (in my case) and wait for that change to reflect. Or you could sign with a different, unused keystore.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have microsoft (hotmail, outlook ...) account on your android, to solve this problem.